# Dynamically assign id to tr tag using struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have an `ArrayList` of firms with `firmId, firmName,address,phoneNumber,status`  fields. I want to dynamically assign `firmId` to each row.

```jsp
<s:iterator value="firms">
<tr>

    <td align="left" class="Edit">
        <img src="../images/btn-edit.png" title="Edit" width="27" height="25" alt='Edit' />
    </td>
    <td align="left"><s:property value="firmName" /></td>
    <td align="left"><s:property value="address" /></td>
    <td align="left"><s:property value="phoneNumber" /></td>
    <td align="left"><s:property value="status" /></td>

</tr>

</s:iterator>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you access any other property:

```jsp
<s:iterator value="firms">
  <tr id="firm-<s:property value='firmId'/>">
```

Note that a numeric id is not a valid id, you should prepend a string constant as shown.